# $('td').each(); not working for all the tables in page.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 tables in a page, and wrote the following to do something with all the  elements.

```
$('td').each(function(){
    //do something
});
```

But it works only for the first table. How do I fix this?

Comment: try with `$('table td').each`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: does `$('td').length` give you what you'd expect?

Comment: Your example should work.  You have some larger issue at play (like trying to access a dynamically generated table before it is there).  You should paste more code.  Note that $().each needs uses and index and an element reference $().each(function(idx, el){});

Comment: @atmd, yes. It does. There are 3 tables each with 30 <td>s. And $('td').length returns 90.

Comment: So that suggest's its working fine, why do you think it isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

May be something wrong with your markups

```js
$('td').each(function(idx){
   document.write("<br/>idx: " + idx)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>d</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>f</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr> <td>g</td>
  <td>h</td>
  <td>i</td></tr>
</table>
```

Js code

```
$(function(){
 $('table tr td').each(function(i, e){
   //do something here
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .find():

```
var td = $('table').find('td');
    td.each(function(k,v){
       alert(k+" - "+v);
    }); 






  <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```